# How to access a named range in Excel-VBA with multiple areas?

Tags: excel, vba

All works fine with a one-area range:
Select cells A1 and B1 and give it the name "foo".

```
?ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("foo").RefersTo
 =Tabelle1!$A$1:$B$1
?ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("foo").RefersToRange.Address
 $A$1:$B$1
```

However, two-area ranges will fail (Excel 2010):
Click cells A2 and B2 with **ctrl pressed** and give it the name "bar".

```
 ?ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("bar").RefersTo
  =Tabelle1!$A$2,Tabelle1!$B$2
 ?ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("bar").RefersToRange.Address
  -> Run-time error '1004'
```

Why can't we get the range the "bar"-name refers to?

Is there a workaround **not using** `sheet.Range("bar")` as I don't know which sheet holds the name?

Comment: Note `.RefersToRange.Address` appears to work as desired when I tested in Excel 2003.

Comment: @A.Webb I've tested on 2003 as well and it fails. Are you sure you created a multiarea range?

Comment: @GSerg  Yes, I get, for example `?ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("bar").RefersToRange.Address`
`$A$1,$C$1`

Comment: @A.Webb Ah. It would appear this works indeed if the Excel language is English. Doesn't work on [at least some] localized versions. Apparently this internally retrieves range address in local form and then treats it in en-us way (or the other way round). Another PITA Excel bug for my collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the global `Range`, not a `sheet.Range`:

```
? Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("bar").RefersTo).Address
```

<s>In order to avoid possible cross-workbook gotchas you can use `ConvertFormula` to add workbook name to the range:</s>

```
? ThisWorkbook.Names("bar").RefersTo
  =Sheet1!$A$2,Sheet1!$B$2

? Application.ConvertFormula(ThisWorkbook.Names("bar").RefersTo, xlA1, xlA1)
  =[Book1]Sheet1!$A$2,[Book1]Sheet1!$B$2

? Application.Range(Application.ConvertFormula(ThisWorkbook.Names("bar").RefersTo, xlA1, xlA1)).Address
  =$A$2,$B$2
```

Comment: Global range refers to the active workbook. There may be multiple workbooks cross-accessing named ranges, though that is not my use case, currently.

Comment: I know that. There is no Workbook.Range unfortunately. I'm actually quite surprised to learn `RefersToRange` falis on multiarea addresses. I suppose you're not going to parse the `RefersTo` yourself?

Comment: No way, no brittle string operations.

Comment: @amadeus No, actually doesn't look good. It always appends the active workbook name, not the name of the workbook to which the range belongs. Which is understandable if you think about it. Sadly, even relative R1C1 addressing does not help if I pass the correct anchor cell as the last parameter to `ConvertFormula`, it would still use the active workbook name.

Answer (score 0):

A wrinkle here is that `RefersToRange` fails for a multi-area named range defined by:

```
=Sheet1!$B$2 + Sheet1!$D$4
```

But it will work for:

```
=Sheet1!$B$2 , Sheet1!$D$4
```

The difference being `,` vs `+`.